# Create Sharepoint managed metadata for interdepartmental column but maintenance should be intradepartmental

Tags: security, sharepoint, metadata, sharepoint-2013

I want to create a **managed metadata** (in the term store) column in **Sharepoint** 2013 called 'Subject'.

```
Subject
  HR
    Personnel
  IT
    App1
    App2
  Finance
    Invoices
```

But it should be possible to manage the subject intradepartmental, I want to appoint **someone from HR to manage the HR subjects and someone else to maintain the IT subjects**.

It should be possible to have a column which allows the users to **choose only from the IT subjects**, but another column should make it possible to **choose from all subjects**.

With the above structure it would be possible to create the columns but I think security to manage only departmental subjects isn't possible.

For security to work I could create the following structure:

```
Subject HR
  Personnel
Subject IT
  App1
  App2
Subject Finance
  Invoices
```

But I guess this would make it hard (impossible?) to create a column that gives the user the opportunity to choose from all Subjects.

Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by making 2 groups, HR and IT, added a termset called Subjects in both groups, added a term HR in HR/Subjects and a term IT in IT/Subjects. this way I can make 2 different people group manager, one for HHR and one for IT.

Then I made a new group called Subjects with a term set Subjects and pinned HR/Subjects/HR and IT/Subjects/IT in Subjects/Subjects.

Hope this can help someone ...